# z-index cross-browser incompatiblity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser, z-index

This is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Perspective11/pen/BzoZWL)  of a very short simple code.

```
only html and css, and Bootstrap
```

It shows a very basic Bootstrap carousel with an added white transparent overlay. The carousel caption should appear on top of the overlay, but it doesn't appear like that in Chrome Browser. Firefox,though, is showing it like it's supposed to.

I want the text to slide and appear on top of the still overlay on all browsers.

Comment: A link to CodePen is great but can you put the relevant piece of code in question for people to help you better?

Comment: @PraveenPuglia the relevant part is the z-index of the captions. I want them to appear on top of everything. they are not and i just wanna know why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using:

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner > .item::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Instead of a separate *overlay* container?
I mean there even is a `content: ''` in your CSS for this container, so I guess it was or was supposed to be a pseudo element.